# How to disable two submit buttons when one of them is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, razor

I have two submit buttons in a cshtml file.

```
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="accept" id="buttonAccept">Accept</button>

<button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="refuse" id="buttonRefuse"Refuse</button>
```

I am trying to disable these two buttons when either one of them is clicked.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: How are you handling the click action? Is it at the client side or server side?

Comment: can you use js for this

Comment: @Praveen I use Request.Form["SubmitButton"] to reach to the clicked button

Comment: Why do you even have 2x submit button?!

Comment: you already got solution but you can also check my solution bellow using jquery you can do that in one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the similar code for both buttons. `onClick` on one button disable the other button and so.

```
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="accept" id="buttonAccept" onclick="return foo();">Accept</button>

function foo() {
   document.getElementById("buttonAccept").disabled = true;
   document.getElementById("buttonRefuse").disabled = true;
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use javascript (especially jQuery) to reach your purpose.

but, actually when you submit your form, it means your form is sent to your server and it returns new result of your view, so the next steps will happen in the backend, your backend will be responsible to render the result in the way you want.

```
$('#buttonAccept').on("click",function() {
  $('#buttonRefuse').attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

$('#buttonRefuse').on("click",function() {
  $('#buttonAccept').attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: If you use jQuery then this is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
document.getElementsByName("SubmitButton")[0].disabled = true;
document.getElementsByName("SubmitButton")[1].disabled = true;
```

I wouldn't use the index directly though.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do like this.

For Disabling the Button in Front-end using Pure JavaScript

```html
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('ButtonTwo').disabled = true;" type="submit" name="ButtonOne" id="ButtonOne">First</button>

    <button onclick="document.getElementById('ButtonOne').disabled = true;" type="submit" name="ButtonTwo" id="ButtonTwo">Second</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly add `jquery` if your page don't have one

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
```

then add on click event like this

```
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="accept" id="buttonAccept" onclick="EnableDisable()">Accept</button>  
<button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="refuse" id="buttonRefuse" onclick="EnableDisable()">Refuse</button>
```

then you can disable both `submit button` on any of there `click event` like this

```
function EnableDisable() {
  $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
}
```